# Trouble Mocking Lambda withing Unitofwork's Repository

Tags: c#, unit-testing, repository, moq, unit-of-work

I'm using .net 4 with C#, EntityFramework 4, and Moq 4.  I'm attempting to mock my UnitOfWork, a Repository, and finally a method call.

Here is the code I am having trouble with

```
        var unitOfWorkMock = new Mock<UnitOfWork>();
        var cFieldRepositoryMock = new Mock<IRepository<CField>>();

        System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<CField, bool>> query = (x) => x.CID == c && x.FID == parentFID;

        cFieldRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetFirst(query));
```

The Method Signature for GetFirst:

```
          T GetFirst(Expression<Func<T, bool>> query = null,
        Func<IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable<T>> orderBy = null);
```

CField:

```
public class CField
{
    public CField()
    {
       //do stuff
    }
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int FID { get; set; }
    public int CID { get; set; }
}
```

What I expect to happen:
I am expecting that wheh I call my cFieldRepositoryMock's GetFirst method, it will match the lambda expression I pass in against the expression I defined in the  Setup.

What's Happening:
I'm getting a compiler error on the Setup assignment: "An Expression tree may not contain a call or invocation that uses optional arguments"

I am clearly doing something wrong, I'm just not sure what. Any advice is appreciated, I am fairly new to unit testing.

Thanks!
AFrieze

Comment: Could you post the declaration if CField and the method signature of getfirst()?

Comment: Hi David, I added the requested information.  I am unable to post the entire CField class so I posted the relevant fields with the correct types and accessibility levels.

Comment: Have you trieded adding an argument for the orderBy-Argument (with It.IsAny<...> or null) ? I don't know exactly but I think Moq is using Expressions itself and I think you have to provide *all* Arguments here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The eror you're receiving seems to be actually a [limitation of expressions](http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2010/05/18/caveats-of-c-4-0-optional-parameters/):

To unittest stuff like this consider to use It.IsAny ( as Carsten already suggested ):

```
cFieldRepositoryMock.Setup(x => x.GetFirst(query, It.IsAny<Func<IQueryable<CField>, IOrderedQueryable<CField>>>()));
```